# Issues with Selenium title validation in C# using xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I have the following HTML below that I am trying to verify the title is present when I land on the page. This is in IE 11

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><title>
 Smart Tracking System
</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/desktopicon.ico" /><link href="../App_Themes/appthemes/appstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/appthemes/calendarstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/appthemes/tabsstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>
```

When I copy the xpath from Firefox source code, it says the xpath is:
/html/head/title

I am using C# code to do the validation but I keep getting "LoadableComponentException..."

```
private By textlabelPageHeader = By.XPath("//h1[@class='title' and text()='Smart Tracking System']");
```

What am I not doing?? Please any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you averse to using `IWebDriver.Title`?

Comment: Please elaborate. I am new to Selenium and C#

Comment: Do you need to get *header* from page *body* or *title* from page *head*? It's not quite clear

Comment: Just the title from the page head. So I am trying to validate that this title "Smart Tracking System" is present

Comment: You can get that from the `Title` property of your webdriver: `string title = driver.Title;`

Comment: You really should spend some time googling your own question before posting. Being new is not an excuse. Take time to educate yourself so you can learn the basics on your own and save questions for those that aren't covered elsewhere.

Comment: haha... you sound very salty. Of course I saw the other question, but their solution did not resolve my issue. Help if you can or just go have a seat somewhere else!